# Namespace attributes in Builder gem

Tags: xml, namespaces, builder

Im trying to build out this sample in a Ruby on Rails app with the [builder gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/builder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ngp:contactGet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ngp="http://www.ngpsoftware.com/ngpapi"> 
<campaignID>1033</campaignID> 
<contactID>199434</contactID> 
</ngp:contactGet>
```

I can generate a tag with a namespace as follows:

```
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
xml.ngp :contactGet
```

...but I can't get an attribute inside that tag.

I would think that

```
xml.ngp :contactGet("xmlns:xsi" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" "xmlns:ngp" =>"http://www.ngpsoftware.com/ngpapi"
```

would work but it doesn't.

Please Help!

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out:

```
xml.tag!('gp:contactGet', {"xmlns:xsi"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xmlns:ngp"=>"http://www.ngpsoftware.com/ngpapi"}) do 
  xml.campaignID("1033")
  xml.contactID("199434")
end
```

Produces...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gp:contactGet xmlns:ngp="http://www.ngpsoftware.com/ngpapi" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <campaignID>1033</campaignID>
  <contactID>199434</contactID>
</gp:contactGet><to_s/>
```

Answer (score 2):

From Builder's doc: http://builder.rubyforge.org/

> Some support for XML namespaces is now available. If the first
>   argument to a tag call is a symbol, it will be joined to the tag to
>   produce a namespace:tag combination. It is easier to show this than
>   describe it.
>
> xml.SOAP :Envelope do ... end
>
> Just put a space before the colon in a namespace to produce the right form for builder (e.g.
>   "SOAP:Envelope" => "xml.SOAP :Envelope")

So, you can write like this:

```
xml.gp :contactGet do
  xml.campaignID("1033")
  xml.contactID("199434")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax instead of `xml.tag!('gp:contactGet')`

```
xml.gp :contactGet do 
  xml.contactID, "199434"
end
```

Also if you need namespaces for tags within the block, you can use the following syntax. I could not find this information anywhere else so adding it here.

```
xml.tag!('gp:contactGet') do 
  xml.gp :contactID, "199434"
end
```

To give the following markup:

```
<gp:contactGet>
  <gp:contactID>199434</gp:contactID>
</gp:contactGet>
```